# Run Javascript on a UIWebView that is loading an outside website

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

So I'm trying to write a program that automatically fills in a form on a website. I wrote some js that does that, and I'm trying to run it on an already loaded website using a UIWebView (swift).

Here's what I'm trying to do.

1. Load a webview with the url amazon.com
2. Javascript activates and fills in form

I've googled around and saw there is a method for WKWebView called evaluateJavascript, but it gives me an undefined error each time, is there another way to do this? (or is it impossible)

**Alternative Idea**

if there is a way to display amazon.com in a local html document and run js in that same document, that will also work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is possible, you're on the right track, try something like this:

```
    let js = "document.getElementById('ap_email').value = 'foo@bar.com'"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
```